# C++11 container of borrowed unique_ptrs

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, lifetime, ownership

I have a vector of unique_ptrs and want to filter it into a new vector of the same type.

```
vector<unique_ptr<Thing>> filter_things(const vector<unique_ptr<Thing>> &things) {
    vector<unique_ptr<Thing>> things;
    // i want the above line to be something like: vector<const unique_ptr<Thing> &>
    // but I don't think this is valid

    for (const unique_ptr<Thing> &thing : things) {
        if (check(thing)) {
            filtered.push_back(thing);  // this part shouldn't work since it
                                        // would duplicate a unique_ptr
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

I want the caller to maintain ownership of all the Things. I want the return value of this function to be purely read only (const), and I don't want to make copies as it is very expensive to copy a Thing.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Is this possible with unique_ptrs?

In some sense, we are creating multiple references by returning a new vector of references, so unique_ptr may not make sense. However, it is purely read only! So there should be some way to make this work. The lifetime of ``things'' is guaranteed to be larger than the filtered things.

Note that the caller owns the parameter supplied.

Comment: You should either share the ownership with std::shared_ptr or allocate for copies. It doesn't make sense to share ownership with `unique_ptr` as the name of it represents.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design... Are you *sure* you want to use `std::unique_ptr` here? `std::shared_ptr` would make much more sense if you want to have multiple owners.

Comment: you could create `reference_wrapper`s with `ref`

Comment: I want to indicate that whoever uses the return value of the function does not control the lifespan of the Things.

Comment: You could simply store raw pointers in the filtered vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reference_wrapper` from `<functional>`

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Thing {};

using PThing = unique_ptr<Thing>;
using RefThing = reference_wrapper<const PThing>;

vector<RefThing> filter_things( const vector<PThing>& things )
{
    vector<RefThing> filtered;
    int i = 0;
    for( auto&& thing : things )
    {
        if( i++%2 )
            filtered.push_back( ref(thing) );
    }
    return filtered;
}

int main()
{
    vector<PThing> vec;
    vector<RefThing> flt;

    vec.resize(25);
    flt = filter_things(vec);

    cout << flt.size() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is getting a filtered set of element not an actual container containing them, `boost::range` can be a good solution.

```
auto filtered_range(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> &things) {
  return things | boost::adaptors::filtered([](const auto& thing) {
    return check(thing);
  });
}
```

I used some of c++14 syntax but I don't think it's hard to make it to c++11.

You can use it like this.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing> > things;
for(const auto& thing : filtered_range(things)) {
  // do whatever you want with things satisfying 'check()'
}
```

One of disadvantages is that the range itself is not a container so if you traverse the range more than once, every 'thing' will be checked if it satisfies `check()`.

If a container storing the checked things AND controlling the lifetime of things are what you really want, I would prefer using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing> >` and returning `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Thing> >`. You can check if it's really one and the only ptr to a thing with `std::shared_ptr::unique()` before deleting it from `things`.